How to properly use Multer as a function not middleware in ExpressJS TS?
I know this question is answered previously as well BUT the given answer does not work for me.
I have the following code
import { ALBResult } from 'aws-lambda';
import { Response as ExpressResponse, Request } from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';

import { logger } from '../../../logger';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './build/uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
        cb(null, `${uniqueSuffix}-${file.originalname}`);
    },
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
}).single('dd');

export default async (req: Request, res: ExpressResponse): Promise<ALBResult> => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        upload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                logger.error('An error occurred when uploading. %o', err);

                const r = res.status(500).send();
                r.end();
                return resolve(r);
            }

            // Everything went fine.
            return resolve(
                res
                    .status(200)
                    .json({
                        id: 1,
                    })
                    .send(),
            );
        });
    });
};


Uploading a file works great and the web client gets 200 response.
My problem is with handling error cases

I upload a multiform data with wrong name video and not dd like the code above expects
The upload request is stuck into pending in the frontend and does not end!

If I change line 29 and I throw the error throw err then the frontend receives the proper 500 status code BUT is also crashing my server.
I want to send 500 back to the web and keep the server alive.
